# Pandas: split dataset into periods based on some interval

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like

```
id            date
111           2021-08-10
111           2021-08-11
111           2021-08-11
222           2021-08-11
111           2021-08-12
111           2021-08-13
222           2021-08-13
222           2021-08-13
222           2021-08-14
```

And I want to create a column **period** for every **id** if date has changed.

Desire output

```
id            date            period
111           2021-08-10      1
111           2021-08-11      2
111           2021-08-11      2
222           2021-08-11      1
111           2021-08-12      3
111           2021-08-13      4
222           2021-08-13      2
222           2021-08-13      2
222           2021-08-14      3
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If values are sorted, so order is important use [`GroupBy.rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.rank.html):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df['period'] = df.groupby('id')['date'].rank(method='dense').astype(int)
print (df)
    id       date  period
0  111 2021-08-10       1
1  111 2021-08-11       2
2  111 2021-08-11       2
3  222 2021-08-11       1
4  111 2021-08-12       3
5  111 2021-08-13       4
6  222 2021-08-13       2
7  222 2021-08-13       2
8  222 2021-08-14       3
```

If order is not important use custom lambda function with [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html):

```
f = lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0]
df['period'] = df.groupby('id')['date'].transform(f) + 1
```